# jmeter - how to use Apache htpasswd in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying jmeter for the first time. I have to load test a site that has authentication control using Apache htpasswd. I tried setting up the http Authorization manager, but i keep getting this error

Headers size in bytes: 291
Body size in bytes: 491
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 401
Response message: Authorization Required

I have given the site name, username, password given in the Authorization manager. Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it's really Basic authentication? How do you know? What happens if you inject username and password into URL as

```
http://username:password@site/path
```

If result will differ from 401 you could try providing `Base URL` (including the path) along with credentials.

See [How to use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) guide for more details on how to properly configure HTTP Authorization Manager for Basic authentication challenge.

Just in case if anything goes wrong you can also use [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager). Looking into HTTP Request details, Basic HTTP Authentication results in the following HTTP Header:

- Name: Authorization
- Value: Basic [Base64-encoded username:password] string

So you can construct proper authorization header as follows:

1. Add a HTTP Header Manager to your plan
2. Put "Authorization" into "Name" field
3. Put "Basic " into value field (mention space after basic"
4. Now you need to know Base64-encoded value of username and password pair separated by colon. In order to know this

   - navigate to https://www.base64encode.org/
   - put your credentials as "username:password" (without quotes) into form and click "Encode" button
   - append the resulting encoded value to HTTP Header Manager's "Value" stanza, after "Basic "

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! that solution

```
http://username:password@site/path
```

worked. It actually gave me an invalid character error for ":" and I had to replace : with %3A (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and it worked. Thanks again!